# $me = $facebook->api('/me') does not return any value

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a facebook iframe application with the New Graph API php sdk. I am using the basic code to just display my name. But it does not return any value. Some one please help me with this.

```
<?php  

  include_once 'facebook.php';  
  include_once 'config.php';  

  $facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,  
                                 'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY,  
                                 'cookie' => true,));  

  $session = $facebook->getSession();
  $me = null;

  if ($session) {
    try {  
        $uid = $facebook->getUser();
        echo "Hello " . $uid . "<br />";   // This is displayed with my User Id

        $me = $facebook->api('/me');
       echo "Hello " . $me['name'] . "<br />";  // This is not displayed.

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
    }
  }

if ($me) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
```

Why is my name not displayed?

**Edit 1**

If I use the example code that comes with the New Graph API facebook sdk zip folder, I get the following error:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 6: 
 Could not resolve host: graph.facebook.com; 
 No data record of requested type thrown in
 C:\xampplite\htdocs\newtest\facebook.php on line 513
```

where line no 513 is:

```
 $e = new FacebookApiException(array(
    'error_code' => curl_errno($ch),
    'error'      => array(
      'message' => curl_error($ch),
      'type'    => 'CurlException',
    ),
  ));
```

Please explain me what is wrong. I searched for the error explanation in google,but i couldn't get much information. What is the error I have made?

Comment: Did you check the error log? I.e. did $facebook->api throw an exception?

Comment: No, how do I check that? But today, I get my session value itself as null. I did a var dump of my session variable, and it is displayed as NULL

Comment: Have you solved this problem???
I got the same error..
can you help me?
thanks

Answer (score 6):

try writing the following code in the try block where you have called the this($me = $facebook->api('/me');) api.

Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
  Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 2;

Comment: it worked, but can you please tell me what does that two lines do?

Answer (score 1):

let us tack a look at the error by the following script:

```
try {
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $fbme = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) { 
    print_r($e);
}
```

Error:

```
[error] => Array
(
    [message] => Failed to connect to 66.220.147.27: Permission denied
    [type] => CurlException
)
```

outgoing connections are filtered by the server firewall. Refer to your hosting support for additional information how to allow the connection to external host.

Note that you can also disable the firewall, and everything will work well.